# How to add a clear button using ACEDrawingView

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a view to the main view (a subview) where the user can hand draw, I'm trying to do this using ACEDrawingView, my issue is that I don't know how use the clear, undo etc. features.

This is how I'm using ACEDrawingView which works fine but without any buttons.

1- Created a Simple App project
2- Added a view and set "ACEDrawingView" as its class
3- Complied-ran and it worked great

The question is, how can I clear, undo etc. I tried calling the clear method but nothing happens.

Here is what I have tried that didn't work.

1- Added a button to the main view and created an action for it
2- Imported ACEDrawingView
3- Created an instance of ACEDrawingView

```
ACEDrawingView *draw = [[ACEDrawingView alloc] init];
```

4- Called the clear method from ACEDrawingView using the action created in step one

```
[draw clear];
```

When I tap the button nothing happens, I don't get any no errors either.

How can I add a clear or undo button?

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at the [demo application](https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView) ACEDrawingView provides on GitHub to see how they're doing it. It looks like they use undo, redo and clear in the demo so it should give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to add the drawing view and buttons using ACEDrawingView;

1- Create a Simple App project

2- Import (drag and drop) the following four classes to your project

> ACEDrawingTools.h
>   ACEDrawingTools.m
>   ACEDrawingView.h
>   ACEDrawingView.h

3- Click the main storyboard and add a view (a view, not a view controller).

4- Select the view you added in step 3 and set "ACEDrawingView" as its class.

5- Compile and run

*It this point you should see an empty view where the only thing you can do is draw, no buttons yet.*

**Now let add some buttons.**

6- Go to the main storyboard and add three buttons right below the view you added in step 3, name the buttons clear, undo and redo.

7-  Create an action for each button and name them respectably clear, redo and undo

8-  Go to viewController.h and add `@class ACEDrawingView;` right after the import statements and `@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet ACEDrawingView *drawingView;` right after the interface

9- Go to the main storyboard and link the view you added in step 3 to the outlet drawingView (added in step 8)

10- Got to viewController.m and import ACEDrawingView.h

```
#import "ACEDrawingView.h"
```

11- Go to the action for clear and add

```
[self.drawingView clear];
```

12- Go to the action for redo and add

```
[self.drawingView redoLatestStep];
```

13- Go to the action for undo and add

```
[self.drawingView undoLatestStep];
```

14- Done.
*You should now be able to clear, undo and redo*